# Centring two input boxes using center-block and span

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, center

Hi I am trying to center 2 input boxes in a row by adapting an example I saw here that was used for 1.  I am trying to use span to get the 2 boxes together but they remain on top of each other and anchored left.  Can someone help?

```
            <div class="row">
            <div class="center-block col-md-12" style="float: left; display: inline">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary register">
                    <span>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="Email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="Password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                        </div>
                    </span>
                </button>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I think you are trying to do:

```
<div class=".container-fluid">
    <div class="row panel panel-default panel-heading">
        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-4">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="Email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="Password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5p451h2u/)

Note that you are setting two textboxes within a `button`, which is wrong

Also, the size of your screen matters as the controls would stack on top of each other in case the screen size decreases.